# What does "Controller Key" mean in Interface Builder > Inspector > Bindings?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

I can't find in the Docs where they explain all those fields and what they mean. Especially "Controller Key" is not clear to me.

Answer (score 5):

[Copying [my answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774022/cocoa-key-value-bindings-what-are-the-explanations-of-the-various-options-for-co/1774327#1774327)…]

The controller key is the key for the (property of the controller object) you're binding to. The model key path is the key path by which the bound object can ask the model objects for more basic objects, such as strings or images, or for other model objects (i.e., drill down into the model).

An example: Let's say you have a Person objects in an array controller, and each Person has a `name`. You bind a table column to the array controller, controller key `arrangedObjects` (thereby getting the model objects), model key path `name` (thereby getting the value objects).

A more complex example: Suppose you have an array controller of Departments. Each Department contains Persons (employees in the department). You can bind your People array controller to the Departments controller, controller key `arrangedObjects` (getting the Department model objects), model key path `@distinctUnionOfObjects.employees` (getting the Person model objects), and then bind a table column to the People controller, controller key `arrangedObjects`, model key path `name`.

That table would be for people who work for your company; if you have a separate table of *prospective* employees, you can create Person objects for them, too, and they won't show up in the table of existing employees because they're not in a Department. When you hire them, you'll add them to one or more Departments; then, they'll show up in the People array controller automatically, because that array controller is observing the `employees` of all of the Departments.

Comment: Dave Gallagher: Actually not. Both examples are of a single table view, listing Person objects. The former example has these as the top level of the model; the latter example has all Persons only accessible through Departments. The two examples show that the same single list can be easily implemented for both models using Bindings.

Answer (score 4):

The Controller Key pop-up menu is a way to help you discover what keys the controller (typically a NSArrayController, NSObjectController or a NSTreeController) presents.

The best example is the `selection` key of NSArrayControllers, which contains the set of selected objects. What is confusing is the NSObjectController presents a 'selection' key too, although the controller can control only a single object (therefore the selection = the object).

I agree that it is not clear at all. I personnally began to understand it when I bound my objects programmatically (i.e. using the `bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` method).

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with key-value coding. You can bind a control in IB to a value in your controller. To connect that value, you have to specify the keypath to it. For example, if you have a textfield in IB and you want to bind it to say a field called 'name' in your controller, you would specify 'name' as the keypath. You then need to set up your name field in your controller to be accessible through key-value coding. This is done in 10.5 by using the @property and @synthesize specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this topic:  [Cocoa Key Value Bindings: What are the explanations of the various options for Controller Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774022/cocoa-key-value-bindings-what-are-the-explanations-of-the-various-options-for-co/2440537#2440537)

I posted an explanation of where to find definitions for all Controller Key's there.